# Spring boot Scheduler is being executed randomly not according to fixedDelay

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have recently switched from `@Scheduled(cron="")` to `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=)` because after few hours of application working scheduled tasks just stoped to being executed until application restart.
Now I have something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"pl.corpnet.bst"})
@ComponentScan
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AiostApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        SpringApplication.run(AiostApplication.class, args);

    }


}
```

and scheduled method which I want to execute every 5min (logic just send GET request to `OpenStack API` and load results to `DB`)

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
  public void reportCurrentTime() throws JSONException, ParseException, UnknownHostException {
    Set<Thread> ts = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    log.info("Running threads {}",ts.size());
    List<IaasApi> apis = iaasApiRepository.findAll();
        ... logic here
    }
```

My guess it was somehow made by Thread lock and by investigating more and putting

```
        Set<Thread> ts = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        for (Thread t : ts) {
            log.info(t.getName()+ " "+ t.getState());
        }
```

I can see multiple (overall 27 threads just after starting the app)
`https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8` in `WAITING` state

Can anyone give me a hint if it is a proper way of working or I misconfigured  something?

Comment: Did you find the cause of it?

Answer (score 2):

With `fixedDelay`, [Sprint starts counting the delay after the method stops executing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). If you want it to run exactly every 5 minutes you should use `fixedRate`, which starts counting right after the method starts running so it will always happen exactly every 5 minutes. If the last execution hasn't finished yet, Spring will create another Thread to run the task again.

Comment: Is there anyway to put timeout on specific task?

Comment: Yes, you should look into the @Async annotation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async